# What does #! mean in a website link mean?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)
>   [Hashbang versus URI parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523140/hashbang-versus-uri-parse)

What would the difference between example.com/index.html and http://www.example.com/#!stories be? I would love to understand what the significance of the #! is?

Comment: [hashbang](http://www.hashbang.org/) (shebang, pound!, etc.) It's usually part of a dynamic loading URI interface, with the `#!` part having to do with the dynamic loading link part. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523140/hashbang-versus-uri-parse

Comment: @Jared Farrish: shebang is used for script headers and has nothing to do with links.

Comment: AFAIK it's used for crawl-able AJAX content

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - My point was that's what people sometimes call it. Some bitch about hashbang, whatever.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: sure, let's just call everything marklar...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - I concur, your excaliburness. `;)` Good point, huzza, you got it dead-on. If you clicked the link in my first comment, maybe you would have realized I excaliburnated the marklar.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I'm not a native speaker, no idea what you intended to say...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - It doesn't matter. The Dude abides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [URL fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It's used by the client to indicate how the content at this URL should be handled. In most cases, it tells the browser to seek to a certain named anchor that's on the page. Sometimes, with Javascript, it is used to reload the page and allow some script to re-run. And in some cases, it's used [to make AJAX applications crawlable by google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

Answer (score 0):

The `#` in links is an skiplink to an ancor inside the `HTML`.

Sometimes this kind of links are used by javascript frameworks like [jquery](http://jquery.com/).